# C++ Exception vs. Error Proxy

Tags: c++

I've been part of the 'no-exception' camp, but not religiously so. I have a question about an argument frequently advanced by the proponents of using exceptions.

So my biggest (only) gripe with exceptions in C++ is the unpredictability of code. I want to be able to look at code (without any IDEs, in VIM) and see exactly what it does in all cases. With exceptions the logic flow is not obvious as the throw and catch can be many logical layers apart.

The typical counter of pro-exception response is: "Yes, that sucks. But nested error codes suck more."

Well, yeah, but that's **not** the alternative.

Say you have a class called MyErrorProxy with a virtual handleMyXYZError(), and if you know your MyClass might get an XYZ error, and you want to handle it many logical layers away, you pass it a pointer to MyErrorProxy (which can be a mixin, an interface, or just a centralized error handling class)? You don't want to pass pointers? Fine, make it a thread-safe singleton. This requires more plumbing, but it is *explicit* and very easy to track logic flow.

That is how I've been coding for a long time.

Now my question is: what are the real drawbacks of doing this? Will you get angry if you see this code long after I'm gone and you're maintaining it? Would you really rather prefer try(s) and catch(es) instead of this mechanism and why?

Comment: What if an unexpected error happens?

Comment: It sounds as if you've encountered some bad experiences with exceptions. Most of the time, good use of exceptions don't have them unwinding all the way up the application. Handling them at the level of the caller, or the caller's caller is usually more understandable.

Comment: How about errors in object's constructor?

Comment: Too argumentative for SO. That said, I'm happy to argue. Exceptions are not unpredictable. When you throw an exception, *you don't care about anything after that*. Why do you feel the need to track down where it ends up? It's not your function's concern. It is a good thing that exceptions fundamentally change the flow of your program, because a state of error is fundamentally different than a state of correctness.

Comment: @GManNickG sorry, my question is not trying to start flame war. I am asking whether my solution to not using them would make you wince :) and why. I don't understand what you mean about not caring when throwing exceptions - if you look at the design of the whole solution, shouldn't you care how things work??? Unpredictability that I'm talking about is tracing through unfamiliar code for the first time and realizing that control is not doing what you expect because someone went overboard w/ exceptions (something I could fix with either -fno-exceptions or firing them - latter not an option).

Comment: @ForEver You can call the error proxy from the constructor. Or are you talking about new failing?

Comment: "I want to be able to [...]" then don't use C++. Exceptions are part of the language, the standard library facilities and some language built in functionality uses them, you can't get around them.

Comment: @Sam - I can always have a handleUnkownError(), whatever that might be.

Comment: @suslik: Even if you really didn't intend to start a flame war, your started your post with an argument aginst exceptions. If you just want thoughts on your code, you could say "Here's a way of handling errors, any flaws?" without the intro (still possibly too subjective though, but less so). But I think the reason you did include your initial argument was because you knew we'd just say "why do any of that, just use exceptions". :) And as others have mentioned, you seem to already hold a grudge against exceptions for whatever reason, so there's no point in even going there.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - don't take this the wrong way, but your comment has nothing to do with my question. There are many reasons why you "May want to [...]. Things like lack of RTTI support, which I had to deal with quite a lot.

Comment: To purely comment on the proposal, it seems like it's just a poorly done implementation of exceptions. The only difference is that it's not a language feature, so it's messier and you lose the fundamental difference in execution path, which is critical in keeping your code from continuing in an error state.

Comment: @suslik: If your implementation lacks RTTI support, it is not C++.

Comment: @suslik: If your implementation lacks RTTI, then your design *with a virtual handleMyXYZError()* is broken. If you want a civilized discussion you should state what the real situation is. And don't backtrack and change the rules with every comment just to counter argument a proposal if your solution would not work with the new rules either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very good idea.  It sounds like a messy way to pass error codes around.  If you don't want to use exceptions, then use error codes.  At least with error codes people will understand what you are doing.

On another note, whenever I see people avoiding exceptions, I think to myself they really don't understand their use.  They're always talking about try/catch.  In reality, properly coded exception use has very few try/catches.  In most of the use cases I've come across, exceptions are just a way to pass an error message back up the stack so it can exit. There's only one try/catch block and it's in main.

Of course, I've coded long lived servers which don't exit.  They log the message passed by the exception, return the same message to the client, and continue in their wait loop.

Bottom line, there should be very few try/catch blocks in your system.  Once you understand that, then the logic flow for exception becomes easy to understand.  In fact, it's designed into the system.